# Finding the normalisation constant of a wavefunction in a box

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, calculus

There is a 1D wavefunction confined between the lines $x=0$ and $x=L$. Its wavefunction is given by $A \sin kx$ where $k = \frac{n \pi}{L}$. I am asked to find the normalisation constant. To do this I have attempted to integrate the modulus squared between positive and negative infinity but end up getting $0$ for the constant which can't be right.

Here's what I tried:

$$1 = \int^{\infty}_{\infty} \vert \psi \vert^2 dx$$
$$ = A^2 \int^{\infty}_{\infty} \sin^2 kx dx $$
$$ = \frac{A^2}{2}\int^{\infty}_{\infty} (1 - \cos 2kx) dx$$
$$ = \frac{A^2}{2} [x - \frac{1}{2kx} \sin2kx]^{\infty}_{-\infty} $$
The first term must be zero as positive infinity take negative infinity is zero, and the right term must be zero as the reciprocal of positive or minus infinity is zero, hence I have:

$$ 1= \frac{A^2}{2} \times 0 $$
$$ 0 = A$$

which can't be right.

Comment: You can't integrate from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ as Roger Vadim noted. The wavefunction is not "defined" outside of the box $[0, L]$. Obviously it can be thought of as being $0$.

Comment: Before studying QM, I would advise a refresh of simple algebra: i) a-(-a) = +2a; ii) no finite value (including zero) of A may be solution of $1=\frac{A^2}{2}\times 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Your wave function is defined only on the interval $[0,L]$, i.e., you need to integrate only over this interval.

Alternatively, one could say that the wave function is defined everywhere, but it is zero outside of $[0,L]$, which gives exactly the same thing.